# Python Pandas Compare 2 Large DataFrames of Text for Similarity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two large dataframes I want to compare.  I want a comparison result capable of a column and / or row wise comparison of similarities by percent. *This part is simple.* However, I want to be able to make the comparison ignore differences based upon value criteria. A small example is below.

```
d1 = {'Sample':pd.Series([101,102,103]), 
      'Col1':pd.Series(['AA','--','BB']), 
      'Col2':pd.Series(['AB','AA','BB'])}
d2 = {'Sample':pd.Series([101,102,103]), 
      'Col1':pd.Series(['BB','AB','--']),
      'Col2':pd.Series(['AB','AA','AB'])}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
df1 = df1.set_index('Sample')
df2 = df2.set_index('Sample')

comparison = df1.eq(df2)

# for column stats
comparison.sum(axis=0) / float(len(df1.index))

# for row stats
comparison.sum(axis=1) / float(len(df1.columns))
```

My problem is that for when `value1='AA' and value2 = '--'` I want them to be viewed as equal (so when one is `'--'` basically always be true) but, otherwise perform a normal Boolean comparison.  I need an efficient way to do this that doesn't include excessive looping as the datasets are quite large.

Comment: hmmm, is possible replace `--` to `AA` and then compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, I'm interpreting *"when one is '--' basically always be true"* to mean that any comparison against `'--'` (no matter what the other value is) should return True. In that case, you could use

```
mask = (df1=='--') | (df2=='--')
```

to find every location where either `df1` or `df2` is equal to `'--'` and then use

```
comparison |= mask
```

to update `comparison`. For example,

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)

N = 10000
df1, df2 = [pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(map(''.join, IT.product(list('ABC'), repeat=2))+['--'], 
                     size=(N, 2)),
    columns=['Col1', 'Col2']) for i in range(2)]


comparison = df1.eq(df2)    
mask = (df1=='--') | (df2=='--')
comparison |= mask

# for column stats
column_stats = comparison.sum(axis=0) / float(len(df1.index))

# for row stats
row_stats = comparison.sum(axis=1) / float(len(df1.columns))
```

Comment: thanks unutbu! That worked well.   I had two dataframes, each with 1326 columns and 62831 rows.  The code ran in 12.14 seconds and gave the correct results (I previously had a very loop intensive base python script which took over 3 hours to compute).

Answer (score 0):

I think loop comprehension should be quite fast:

```
new_columns = []
for col in df1.columns:
    new_columns.append([True if (x==y or x=='--' or y=='--') else False for x,y in zip(df1[col],df2[col])])
results = pd.DataFrame(new_columns).T
results.index = df1.index
```

This outputs the full true/false df.